# Processing numbered files via bash

Tags: bash, shell-script

I have a set of files a.rst.1, a.rst.2, ...., a.rst.5000

I need to run this command for each one:

```
ambpdb -p prmtop < a.rst.x > a.pdb.x
```

Where x represents the number for that file. Is there an easy way to do this via bash?

Answer (score 3):

You could try the `bash` `{1..5000}` construct which is the `bash` builtin equivalent of `$(seq 1 5000)`:

```
for i in {1..5000}; do
   ambpdb -p prmtop < a.rst.$i > a.pdb.$i
done
```

If the higher limit was too big, one alternative would be to use a simple loop counter :

```
i=1
while [ $i -le 5000 ]; do
    ambpdb -p prmtop < a.rst.$i > a.pdb.$i
    i=$((i+1))
done
```

Comment: Thank you! I had tried this, but with 'seq 1 5000' instead. Is there a reason that might work differently? Or was I just doing something dumb?

Comment: @elykl33t The `seq` command should work too. What was the command line that you used?

Comment: I think it may have been an unrelated issue where I made a typo or something. I just wanted to check whether the functionality was the same. Thank you!

Comment: With bash this is possible, too: `while [ ${i:=1} -le 5000 ]; do ambpdb -p prmtop < a.rst.$i > a.pdb.$((i++)); done`

Comment: @Cyrus This is indeed more compact, but, in my case, `i` is my go to value for any small `for` loop that I make, so it would probably already be assigned a value thus resulting in an error/undefined behaviour.

Answer (score 2):

Other way:

```
for f in ./a.rst.*; do
  ambpdb -prmtop < "$f" > "a.pdb.${f##*.}"
done
```